# Cannot build the Google Drive API service in an app bundled with PyInstaller

Tags: python, google-api, pyinstaller, google-api-python-client

When I bundle an app using PyInstaller, the service build method (`googleapiclient.discovery.build`) doesn't work automatically when specifying Google Drive's service name and its version
and I get this error :
`googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: drive  version: v3`

Here is my code sample to reproduce :

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
build("drive", "v3", credentials=credentials)
```

(you need to set the credentials, I use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope)

Here are the options I use for bundling my app with the `pyinstaller` command :

```
--onefile --additional-hooks-dir=./hooks
```

I achieved to make it work for any other service by specifying the `discoveryServiceUrl` argument and setting it to the correct discovery url, which should be
`https://SERVICE.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=VERSION`
(IE `https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4` for Google Sheets)

But it seems that Google Drive doesn't have a standard discovery url and I couldn't find the correct one

I tried to build drive using the sheets discovery url and the build doesn't fail, but then I can't use the drive API methods (like `.files()`)

I also tried to manually add the googleapiclient hook that you can find there : https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/blob/master/src/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks/hook-googleapiclient.model.py
(it should be added automatically when bundling) but it doesn't work either

Do you know a way to make it work for Google Drive ? do I have to change something in the way i run PyInstaller ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change
build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
to
build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials, static_discovery=False)